# Problems running Java from Atom

Tags: java, atom-editor

I currently don't have a working way to edit and run Java on my computer, so I'm trying to get Atom working with Java (I realize it's not a Java IDE and I'm not trying to make it one, I just want to be able to do some light Java work on my laptop). I've installed the script and instant-build packages for Atom and wrote the following test code in a file called "main.java' in my project folder:

```
class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("please");
  }
}
```

When I try to run the code with cmd+i (I'm on a 2012 MacBook Pro) and get the following error message:Error: Could not find or load main class main.

I'd be happy to provide any further information; thanks for helping!

Comment: You need to set the classpath variable or command line -cp option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to name your file with the first letter in upper case `Main.java`, since it must match the name of your class

Comment: Hi again! I'm having the same problem with a new project. The main file is again called "Main.java" and the code is as follows: class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("pls");
  }
} Edit: sorry about the spacing, it won't let me do new lines...

Comment: @A.Cook please create a new question since the problem that you describe is completely different to the one answered here.

Answer (score 1):

The huge problem of learning Java is that you need to launch the projects in a very strict way, and setting the classpath is always problematic. The solution lays in the following (pretty enigmatic) line of the "Script" documentation:

```
Project directory should be the source directory; subfolders imply packaging.
```

So, instead of opening a plain file, open the project (folder) with .java classes or define inside the file, the package to which your .java belong.

It's due to the fact that JDE needs to create a virtual target in form of .classess and single .java file definitely can't be launched as standalone file. I suppose that "Script" is not able to locate the source folder when you try to execute seperate .java file.

[Before launching your .java files always "Add Project Folder..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFoO7.png)

Please remember that it's not possible to have several folders opened if they don't belong to the same project. Such situation cause problems of locating the right classpath and in the end javac prompts the error.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated the issue quite easily. If I created a new directory in Atom itself and then tried to run the code it didn't work as your error message came up for me as well. `Error: Could not find or load main class main.`

I used an existing directory and then created a file inside that folder in Atom and ran the same code it worked. I then copied and pasted that same file into the directory of my choice and it worked.

Comment: A suggestion as well - Use the ide-java and linter-javac packages to run Java efficiently on Atom.